# Gather all the Jira Tickets in the lastest Bamboo Release using a Bamboo Script Task

Tags: bash, rest, curl, bamboo

Long time stack**overflow** reader, first post in a very long time, thanks for all the help over the years!

I'm trying to automate the post release process inside of Bamboo, I have a the following structure in my build plan (upstream):

- Build Project

  - Plan

    - Default Stage

      - Job Build JAR

        - Task Git Checkout
        - Task Maven
        - Task create Git Tag in repo

After building my project I have a successful build with i.E. #14 and the tag 'v5.10.4.1' in ButBucket (Git).

Following this I created a Deployment Project (downstream) that has these script tasks:

1. Create fixVersion in Jira
2. Gather all the Jira Tickets in the lastest Bamboo Release
3. Add all Bamboo Release Tickets to Jira Release

The steps use `curl` in some form or another and the REST API either from Jira or Bamboo, **Step 1** works with any problems as long as the *fixVersion* hasn't been created in Jira previously.

For **Step 2** I did a test from my workstation with success using this command to get the issues and save them as a text file for **Step 3** afterwards:

```
curl -X GET --user ${bamboo.user}:${bamboo.password} -H 'X-Atlassian-Token: no-check' "https://server-name/rest/api/latest/result/${bamboo.buildResultKey}.json?expand=jiraIssues" -o >(grep -o -E '"(Ticket-KEY)-\d*"' | tr -d '"' > /tmp/issueKeys.txt) && cat /tmp/issueKeys.txt
```

I tried doing this as a Script Task during my deployment as either inline or file based, this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
# Variables: ${bamboo.user}:${bamboo.password}; ${bamboo.buildResultKey}
# Gather all the Jira Tickets in the lastest Bamboo Release as the second step
 
echo "==> Gather all the Jira Tickets in the lastest Bamboo Release: yes"
 
curl -X GET --user ${bamboo.user}:${bamboo.password} -H 'X-Atlassian-Token: no-check' "https://server-name/rest/api/latest/result/${bamboo.buildResultKey}.json?expand=jiraIssues" -o >(grep -o -E '"(Ticket-KEY)-\d*"' | tr -d '"' > /tmp/issueKeys.txt)
 
echo "==> The following Jira Tickets from the lastest Bamboo Release have been gathered"

# for debugging run this to verfiy the results in the Bamboo deployment logs
cd /tmp/ && ls -la && cat issueKeys.txt && nl issueKeys.txt
```

I ran into the following problems:

- Using https in the curl command on Bamboo itself will log: `curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`
- Using http in the curl command on Bamboo itself will log a `404`:

```
13-Dec.-2023 14:05:53   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
13-Dec.-2023 14:05:53   <html><head>
13-Dec.-2023 14:05:53   <title>404 Not Found</title>
13-Dec.-2023 14:05:53   </head><body>
13-Dec.-2023 14:05:53   <h1>Not Found</h1>
13-Dec.-2023 14:05:53   <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
13-Dec.-2023 14:05:53   <hr>
```

It seems it is not possible to curl the Bamboo REST API from inside of Bamboo it's self but it should be possible, I found this in the Atlassian documentation:
`curl -u <ADMIN_USERNAME>:<PASSWORD> <BAMBOO_URL>/build/admin/ajax/getDashboardSummary.action`

Maybe someone has solved this already but I can't find a thread or documentation. Many thanks for help or ideas!

Comment: I don't know about bamboo scripting, but from the viewpoint of bash `${bamboo.user}` is not a valid bash parameter expansion. Is  bamboo automagically expanding this ?r

Comment: @user1934428 Bamboo has intern variables like ${bamboo.user} which can be stored globally and then accessed when the script is run. This functions without issues and is not a problem in my use case.

Comment: Interesting. If they are only accessed when the script is run, I would be curious to know how this access is implemented. bash can't do it.

Comment: ksh93 supports `${bamboo.user}` variable names. (Just FWIW). AND if you want to use `bash` to run a `curl` command, maybe make `bambooo_user=xxx ; bamboo_pswd=yyy` asignments and use those in your `curl` cmd?  Good luck.

Comment: @ksh93 The variable are not the issue, my problem is that I can't `curl` bamboo from running a script on bamboo even though it should be possible. The variables are the least of my issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research (googling was not a help here) I found the "actual" [Bamboo REST API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/using-the-bamboo-rest-apis/#rest-resources-and-uri-structure) with examples of the correct URI:

```
http://myhost.com:8085/bamboo/rest/api/latest/plan.json
```

or as an example of the structure:

```
http://host:port/rest/api-name/api-version/resource-name
```

In my use case of above where I was trying to `curl` the Bamboo REST API from a Bamboo Script Task, I am now using the following URI without issues:

```
"http://localhost:8085/rest/api/latest/result/${bamboo.buildResultKey}.json?expand=jiraIssues"
```

Issue is resolved.